# MySQLi Prepare SELECT with Multi WHERE Clause Show affected_rows -1

Tags: mysql

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `ticket_number`, `name`, `division`, `position`, `email`, `contact`, `date`, `request_title`, `description`, `status`, `category`, `priority` FROM `ticket_problem` WHERE `ticket_number` = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $ticket_number);
        if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->bind_result($ticket_number,$name,$division,$position,$email,$contact,$date,$request_title,$description,$status,$category,$priority);
                         $tmp = array();
                         while($stmt->fetch()){
                              $user = array();
                              $user['ticket_number'] = $ticket_number;
                              $user['name'] = $name;
                              $user['division'] = $division;
                              $user['position'] = $position;
                              $user['email'] = $email;
                              $user['contact'] = $contact;
                              $user['date'] = $date;
                              $user['request_title'] = $request_title;
                              $user['description'] = $description;
                              $user['status'] = $status;
                              $user['category'] = $category;
                              $user['priority'] = $priority;

                              array_push($tmp,$user);
                         }  
                    $stmt->close();
                    return $user;
                    }
```

that code is work well, but another side below this:

```
if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `ticket_number`, `name`, `division`, `position`, `email`, `contact`, `date`, `request_title`, `description`, `status`, `category`, `priority` FROM `ticket_problem` WHERE `ticket_number` = ? AND `email`=?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ticket_number,$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ticket_number,$name,$division,$position,$email,$contact,$date,$request_title,$description,$status,$category,$priority);
        $tmp = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $user = array();
            $user['ticket_number'] = $ticket_number;
            $user['name'] = $name;
            $user['division'] = $division;
            $user['position'] = $position;
            $user['email'] = $email;
            $user['contact'] = $contact;
            $user['date'] = $date;
            $user['request_title'] = $request_title;
            $user['description'] = $description;
            $user['status'] = $status;
            $user['category'] = $category;
            $user['priority'] = $priority;

            array_push($tmp,$user);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
        }
```

that code have affected row -1, and $user is undefined. i dont know why. that code is same but the different between 2 query i used "AND". here the complete code

```
public function pendingTicketData($email,$ticket_number){
    var_dump($email,$ticket_number);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `ticket_number`,`name`, `email` FROM `ticket_problem` WHERE `email` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if(!$result){
        return false;
    }else{
        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `ticket_number`, `name`, `division`, `position`, `email`, `contact`, `date`, `request_title`, `description`, `status`, `category`, `priority` FROM `ticket_problem` WHERE `ticket_number` = ? AND `email`=?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ticket_number,$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ticket_number,$name,$division,$position,$email,$contact,$date,$request_title,$description,$status,$category,$priority);
        $tmp = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $user = array();
            $user['ticket_number'] = $ticket_number;
            $user['name'] = $name;
            $user['division'] = $division;
            $user['position'] = $position;
            $user['email'] = $email;
            $user['contact'] = $contact;
            $user['date'] = $date;
            $user['request_title'] = $request_title;
            $user['description'] = $description;
            $user['status'] = $status;
            $user['category'] = $category;
            $user['priority'] = $priority;

            array_push($tmp,$user);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code never calls `affected_rows()`.

Comment: before that i use affected_rows and show -1, i've edit the code

Comment: If you call `affected_rows` before you execute a query, it returns `-1`.

Comment: i put the affected_rows after execute()

Comment: Call `store_result()` first to make it retrieve the result set and count them.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't have `affected_rows()` anywhere.

Comment: its a bit change. the store_result() = bool(true) and num_rows or affected_rows int(0). but the error is same Undefined variable: user

Comment: You should be doing `return $tmp;`, not `return $user;`. `$user` is just one row, `$tmp` is the array of all results.

Comment: i've try that and the $tmp had array(0). if you look at first code. the $user can return and $user is define. stil confused why it have different result with same code

Comment: It shouldn't work well. `return $user` just returns the last row. You do `array_push($tmp, $user);`, that puts all the rows into `$tmp`.

Comment: i've do many change in my code, even your recomendation. the problem is in the query on second code that had 'AND'. when i delete that, all code is working with no error, i can return $user with all array inside it. but when i put back 'AND' its going mad again

Comment: why don't you use fetchall intead of all this? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php